# inter process communication messages are exceeding limit

Tags: linux

We are using message queues for interprocess communication where we are pushing messages to message queue,  some time we are exceeding the limit of total messages. Can you give me command to set number of messages to be set as unlimited message queue( IPC).

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -q` might be what you're looking for.